# How can I make bread within one and a half hour?

Tags: baking

Since we have to make bread in cooking class, there is only one and a half hour. Should I use more time to knead, or rise?

Comment: Consider "Bread in a bag", http://allrecipes.com/recipe/bread-in-a-bag/ it helps overcome peoples fear of kneading.

Comment: Does it have to be a yeast bread?  There are plenty of great quickbreads out there.

Comment: Yet another. http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Bread-in-a-Bag

Comment: If it is a cooking class, they should be providing you a recipe suitable for the short time period available.  Some foccacia type breads can be made after only a 20-30 minute rise.

Comment: While there are plenty of quick breads, you could also prepare one batch an hour before class, set it aside and then start a new batch 'in front' of the class and switch them out during the class.

Comment: Do you have bread baking Oven I mean there is a special kind of bread baking oven is coming... in which you just need to pour ingredients and it will automatically make bread with in half to two hour according to the color you want..

Comment: Are you instructing this class? Or are you a student with the bread as an assignment? It's an important distinction, not made clear in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have made bread at home for 45 years, that's my only experience, I  have found that if you use very fresh yeast, allow the bread to rest for a few minutes after you get most of the flour in, and don't keep adding flour once you begin to knead, leave the bread slightly sticky, it will rise faster. there are single rise recipes, I have one using yogurt ,but if I am in a hurry, I add extra yeast.